# BCC Email Log Not Showing in Email Activity Logs

Tags: email, activityhistory

**What I am Doing:** I am sending emails from the contact detail page.

[image]

**The issue I am facing:** When I BCC any email that does not log into activity history.

[image]

It does show the email history for **To** and **CC** . Can someone help me out here if any settings or permissions I need to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce can only see email addresses in the To and CC field. Therefore the email addresses listed under those are the only ones where the email sent can be recorded under activity logs.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385439&type=1), BCC addresses are not displayed in the activity timeline. Therefore, Salesforce can't log any email to the email addresses under the BCC.

[image]

Kindly review similar limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZ8VUAV/salesforce-for-outlook-log-bcc-emails-activity).

Comment: Thanks @vinay , that was helpful!